# SQL CASE SUM WHEN

Tags: sql, sum, case

I'm having trouble trying to figure out a CASE WHEN using SUM in a long query.  Here are the current relevant parts of the query -

```
SELECT _various items_
SUM (nt.GALLONS) AS "2018 CCE gallons"
FROM MQ_CDS_NETTRAN nt
JOIN MQCCNSTORE s ON nt.COSTCENTER = s.COSTCENTER 
WHERE nt.CLRNTSYS = 'CCE'
```

What I need to do now is put

```
WHERE nt.CLRNTSYS IN ('CCE','BAC')
```

and separately sum up the gallons each as "2018 CCE gallons" or "2018 BAC gallons" (there are about 8 other options under CLRNTSYS besides "CCE" or "BAC").  Having not used CASE before, I haven't found an example yet where you SUM a different column based on the data in another column and give it another name.  How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work using `conditional aggregation`:

```
SELECT _various items_
    SUM (CASE WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS = 'CCE' THEN nt.GALLONS END) AS "2018 CCE gallons",
    SUM (CASE WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS = 'BAC' THEN nt.GALLONS END) AS "2018 BAC gallons"
FROM MQ_CDS_NETTRAN nt
JOIN MQCCNSTORE s ON nt.COSTCENTER = s.COSTCENTER 
WHERE nt.CLRNTSYS IN ('CCE','BAC')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use *Condition Aggregate function.*

```
SELECT _various items_
SUM (CASE WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS ='CCE' THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 CCE gallons",
SUM (CASE WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS ='BAC' THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "2018 BAC gallons"
FROM MQ_CDS_NETTRAN nt
JOIN MQCCNSTORE s ON nt.COSTCENTER = s.COSTCENTER 
GROUP BY _various items_
```

Comment: I would not remove the `where` criteria as it could return different core results...

Comment: There is a different WHERE criteria - I just left it out of what I posted because it was a fairly long query to start